# PHP 7.4 depends on two versions of libssl

Tags: php, openssl, linker

I need to compile PHP 7.4 on AlmaLinux 9 with PostgreSQL module support. openssl-devel (3.0) RPM is required by mysql-devel and PHP 7.4 doesn't compile with OpenSSL 3. So I have compiled OpenSSL 1.1 from source and installed it in its default prefix path : /usr/local.
So PHP 7.4 compiles fine this way :

```
$ cd php-7.4.33
$ ./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig' OPENSSL_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib64/ -lssl -lcrypto" --with-apxs2 --with-pgsql --with-external-pcre --enable-mbstring --sysconfdir=/etc --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-pdo --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib --with-zip --with-jpeg --with-pear --with-curl --enable-opcache --with-openssl --with-freetype --with-xpm --with-libdir=lib64 --with-ldap --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --enable-soap --enable-gd --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite --with-curl
$ make -j $(nproc)
```

I got this warning :

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: in function `php_openssl_load_cipher_mode':
php-7.4.33/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6499: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_flags'
```

The problem is that libpq.so depends on libssl.so.3 and PHP on libssl.so.1.1, so ld.so must load two versions of the same SO :

```
$ ldd sapi/cli/php | egrep "ssl|crypto|pq"
        libpq.so.5 => /lib64/libpq.so.5
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
        libssl.so.3 => /lib64/libssl.so.3
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.3
$ ldd /usr/lib64/libpq.so
        libssl.so.3 => /lib64/libssl.so.3
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.3
```

My question is, what ld.so will do if objects of the same name exist in these two SO files (libssl.so.1.1 and libssl.so.3) ? php-cli seems to work but I've not tested PostgreSQL connexion yet.

Many thanks

Comment: PHP 7.4 should use mysqlnd and thus do not actually need mysql-devel. I guess only your MySQL setup would somehow need mysql-devel. If that's so, then one way to solve this is to use your MySQL through containers (e.g. Docker or Podman) with proper port binding. By containerization, all dependencies to your mysql would be contained within it. Then your host environment is free to install whatever you want.

Comment: Another solution is to manually compile an older version of openssl on a custom prefix (e.g. /usr/local/openssl-custom). Then compile your PHP 7.4 with the openssl path specified to there.

Comment: My php binary depends on two versions of libssl, version 1 and 3. What will happens when php binary is loaded ? Will ld.so load libssl.so.1 and libssl.so.3 ? If so, some object symbols of these two SO versions will have the same name and conflict. Or will it only load the first one found in the library search path ? In any way, I wonder how ABI compatibility will be managed beetwen caller and callee !